# Best way to verify thousands of API login calls (php/curl) when the api result takes a few seconds for each

Tags: php, php-curl

I have a database of 20000 users that I need to authenticate against an external provider's service to see if those users are still valid users of the external service. Given that the API login call I need to make for a user can take up to 3 seconds to get a result, what's the best way for me to loop through the 20000 users and store the results? Obviously I cannot code a php page that runs in a browser to do this as the page would be open for up to 60000 seconds (less than ideal). I have thought of a cron job that runs in the background (which I would need to segment into pieces so that not all 20000 are called at once). What's the best approach here? (I have been using php_curl to do individual calls).

Comment: cron job\cli  is the way to go for anything that takes time, and that you don't have to watch. If speed is an issue look at curl_multi

Comment: Is this a useful approach if I do something like 500-1000 calls at a time? https://webkul.com/blog/simultaneous-curl-requests-in-php/ (the API is able to withstand several thousand login calls per second - I have been given the OK to hammer it with big numbers of calls)

Comment: @tim, thanks. I am looking at curl_multi (posted my above comment before I saw yours).

Comment: i have found the optimal number of parallel calls depends a lot on the server. not surprisingly the 4 core server is better running half the 8 core servers number. so you need to test for your self to find your sweet spot